# jQuery.extend and jQuery.fn.extend

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making some test with `extend` and I got a little puzzled after some observations I made. First observations:

```
console.log($.extend === $.fn.extend); // trure
// and since $ === jQuery then ...
console.log(jQuery.extend === jQuery.fn.extend); // true
```

So far so good, isn't it? Given the above results I then thought that doing this:

```
// SNIPPET 1
$.extend({
   log: function(m) {
      console.log(m);
   }
});
```

and this:

```
// SNIPPET 2
$.fn.extend({
   log: function(m) {
      console.log(m);
   }
});
```

was the same very thing. But in fact things stand in a very different way. In fact if you run SNIPPET 1 and then do:

```
$("body").log("whatever");
```

you get an error (log is not defined). But you can do:

```
$.log("whatever");
```

If you run instead SNIPPET 2 you get the opposite result, that is to say:

```
$("body").log("whatever"); // this will work
$.log("whatever"); // this won't
```

What the heck? I appreciate the fact that `.extend` extends the object against which it is executed (`$` vs `$.prototype`) but what I do not get is how iit does it! Expecially given the fact that:

```
$.extend === $.fn.extend // true
```

The function is the same!! How can it produce 2 different results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the function `this` will be different. In the first case it will be `$`, in the second `$.fn`.

Have a look at the [source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.8-stable/src/core.js#L277):

```
jQuery.extend = jQuery.fn.extend = function() {
    var options, name, src, copy, copyIsArray, clone,
        target = arguments[0] || {},
        i = 1,
        length = arguments.length,
        deep = false;

    // ...

    // extend jQuery itself if only one argument is passed
    if ( length === i ) {
        target = this;
         --i;
    }

    // ...
};
```

[Learn more about `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Comment: cool! I thought it must have been something like that causing the observed behaviour. Bad design IMHO.